# Online Webservice Timeout exceeded getting exception details

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, xamarin

So I've been trying to get another exception fixed on the webservice, however, this one appeared today and I can't fix it.

So, let me explain my situation. I have a Xamarin Android program that after a change has been made, it will count down 10 seconds until sending the dataset to the webservice to update a SQL database. So, it will work on updating the database once, however, after it tries sending to the webservice the second time I get the error:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>
```

Here is the part that calls the webservice:

```
async void startUploadCounter()
    {
        SQLWebService.SQLWebService DataService2 = new SQLWebService.SQLWebService();

        await Task.Delay(10000);
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Updating", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        DataService2.updateRooms(rooms,employeeID);
        isEdited = false;
    }
```

And here is the Webservice code:

```
[WebMethod]
public void updateRooms(DataSet rooms, int employeeID)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter($"Select * from Room Where AssignedEMP = {employeeID}", connection);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        dataAdapter.Update(rooms);
        //rooms.Clear();


        //    //rooms.GetChanges();

    }
}
```

Edit: Also I should note, I'm sorry how I'm doing this seems really bad or inefficient, however, I am not really too familiar with webservice things

Comment: Why the 10 second delay in startUploadCounter() ?

Comment: @CurtisShipley It is to decrease the number of calls to the server. I don't know an easier way to add a timer to a Xamarin Android app

Comment: I see. Yes, here probably is a better way to handle this, but it probably isn't the issue. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: @CurtisShipley, Ah, If I can't get my code working, I may rewrite it without the async and include that

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the service is throwing an exception, and the client is having trouble getting information about that exception.

On the webservice side, wrap the insides of the method with a try/catch/finally, and log some simple timing information. Log the time the method is entered, and the time it is exited. Put the exit log message+time in the finally in case it is throwing an exception.

What I would do is separate debugging of the two. Using a tool like Postman, send the web request directly to the webservice and see how long it takes. That will tell you if the problem is on the client or the server.

Also, is REST an option instead of soap? Doing json posts are much easier to test and debug.

Comment: Ah, I guess the error I was getting before is the one that is isn't being pulled. I'll probably have to make another post about that one since it is different than the others